# Browsers not responding to Rails3 force_ssl (Rails 3, https)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My client wants her entire app (all links) to run over HTTPS/SSL.
I put

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

in config/application.rb. However, now Safari and Firefox and Opera are all griping about app, with different errors.
(From Firefox, "ssl_error_rx_record_too_long")

Do I need a certificate? Or is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to do the following to make the entire Rails 3.2 app run over SSL:

1) In config/application.rb, instead of 'config.force_ssl', use the gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer', and

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer
```

2) Create a certificate using openssl/mod-ssl (CentOS)

3) Use "thin" instead of WEBrick - thin seems easier to configure for SSL.
Thin gets configured to use the certificate files generated in Step 2.